# Spring resource server authorization with two different Authorization servers, loses principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my legacy project time before was used authorization server. The server is mandatory for use by some scope services.

Right now I develop new client\user service - resource server (**RS**). The resource server must be integrated with **apigee** to support external clients. Security integration is implemented over **OAuth2-JWT** almost all required elements was used out the box from spring security solutions.

Next step is to add SSO authorization for internal users. SSO authorization server is legacy internal security server. I can handle all required requests to SSO server to get required user details and produce principal wrapped into `UsernamePasswordAuthentificationToken` registering one in the security session context for that. The expectation is all additional requests will be handled successfully using `authorities` specified in the `UsernamePasswordAuthentificationToken`, but security context is empty. In case Without configuring resourceserver with apigee security it works fine.

Considering reason of that lets check filters used in the flow (not all, but most interesting for us):
  - `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`;
  - `OAuth2AuthentificationProcessingFilter` - adds `OAuth2Authentication` object to security context;
  - `CustomSsoFilter` - adds `UsernamePasswordAuthentificationToken` object to security context;
  - `AnonimousAuthentificationFilter` - in case no authentication object in the security context it adds anonymous one.

I've detected that `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` cleans security context in final block. Also `OAuth2AuthentificationProcessingFilter` cleans spring security context in case session is stateless and no authorization token.

Firstly my Idea was to configure `CustomOAuth2AuthentificationProcessingFilter` and maybe `CustomAuthentificationManager` to supress negative effect of `OAuth2AuthentificationProcessingFilter`, but in this way 2 issues for me: i do not know how to remove filter from out the box flow.

### Questions (2 questions but required answer to any of them):

1. How to control remove some filters from security flow (provided by spring boot autoconfiguration) - it helps to close question following my ugly way...
2. How to configure 2 different web filter chain of responcibilies for each security flow (SSO & OAUTH) on the same resource server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexible solution that I've applied was an architect approach that consist of spring out the box part and small trick.

1. Oauth2 JWT client was configured using spring tools and provided all required controls for security flow.
2. To integrate additional security part (for trusted service) I've integrated custom filter (which uses their own custom authentication manager) for each trusted group.
3. Application can't be stateful because cloud and company policy. So session is not our friend to keep any authentication data.
4. Resource service provides small functionality part but authentication in original service is quite expensive. Implement one more security layer with DB storage is also expensive.

### Answer:

5. Internal JWT service doesn't provide direct answer on the questions but covers general need in described issue.

   - Using JWT standard we've boxed authenticated data into token.
   - it is not requires to keep short time tokens in any storage.
   - token with boxed data can be used on our frontend and backend (validating signature and expiration date) simplifying work with multiple trusted sources.
   - one more custom filter (for own JWT service) which used before all others `AuthentificationProcessingFilter`s.
   - filter sensitive with our header: "Authentication":"CustomBearrer JHIg8fU..."

### Disadvantages of this approach:

1. JWT token can't be revoked (we've managed expiration time 5 min, but each request uses newly generated token).
2. External services should have different Authentication approaches or different income url endpoints to verify data only in owner service.